# Javascript get all first children elements

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="container">
    <p><p></p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

The result I want is this:  p,p

I don't want to get all the p tags under the "container", only the first child layer and plain javascript.  Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

Heres what I've tried:

```
document.getElementById(container).getElementsByTagName('p');
```

but this will return p, p, p.  I just want the first child layer (im not sure what its called but I dont want the childrens children, I just want the first set of children)

Edit:

This question is WRONGFULLY marked as duplicate.  I'm not asking to get the first-child.

***ANSWER:***
by sminutoli:  **document.querySelectorAll('#container > p')**

Thank you sir you are a genious.

Edit:  Jakar, in that scenario I would still only want the p's.  sminutoli provided the correct answer.

Comment: Huh? So you don't want the P's inner P? **What have you tried so far**?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('#container > p') is the answer here.

Comment: I took from this question that they were attempting to get all `p` that was the first child of an element. So far no reply does that and duplicate answer does not help with that either.

Comment: BTW You can´t put a `<p>` inside a `<p>`, it´s against the HTML spec and you´ll end in weird results.

Comment: What you have is OK. You can do `document.getElementById(container).getElementsByTagName('p')[0]` that will get you the first `<p>` that is because `getELementsByTagName` returns an array, so just select the first element of that array using `[0]`

Comment: What if you had `<container><div></div><p><p></p></p><p></p></container>`? would you then want `div,p,p` or just `p,p`? There's also `container = document.getElementById(id); var children = container.children;//or container.childNodes`